# How do I construct a base class which receives a reference argument?

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, radix, rvalue

I can't compile the following code using g++ 4.1.2:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
    public:
};

std::auto_ptr<A> GetA()
{
    return std::auto_ptr<A>(new A);
}

class B
{
    B(std::auto_ptr<A>& pA)
    {
    }
};

class C : public B
{
    C() : B(GetA())
    {
    }
};
```

I get:

> invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type `std::auto_ptr<A>` to type `std::auto_ptr<A>&`

The problem is I can't define a variable and pass its reference because I am inside a initialization list.

How can I do that when I am only allowed to change class `C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can *only* change C, you could do something like:

```
class C: public B
{
    explicit C(std::auto_ptr<A>& pA) : B(pA) {}

public:
    static C *GetC()
    {
        std::auto_ptr<A> pA = GetA();
        return new C(pA);
    }
};
```

The problem is trying to bind a non-const reference to the temporary returned by `GetA`. If you can assign that to a variable first, you have an lvalue and it works ok.

As Alex B <del>says</del> said (deleted answer), if you can change B, it would be better to take that `auto_ptr` argument by value; and if you can change compiler, it would be better to use `unique_ptr` and move semantics instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what B does with the passed in reference.

- If B is going to take a copy of the argument, then make the argument a const &
- If B is going to hold a reference to the argument then you need whatever is passed in to have a longer lifetime than the instantiation of B.  (As mentioned already, the temporary created by a call to GetA() doesn't.)